# Update <div> content on a <select> change with php

Tags: php, jquery, html, select, onchange

My goal is to show a second **"select"** in a **"div"** with options depending on the selection made by the user on the first **"select"**.

The first **"select"** is a list of regions, while the second is the list of provinces in the forementioned region.

The function **'change'** should update the div **'province'**, passing a value to another php file used for determining the provinces, with the second select but that doesn't happen.

Main page:

```
<?php
$region= array("","Abruzzo", "Basilicata", "Calabria");
?>
<html>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js">
       function change(value) {
            $('province').load('select.php?id='+ value);
       }
   </script>

   <body>
      <div>
         <select  onchange="change.call(this.value)">
            <?php
              for($i=0;$i<count($region);$i++)
              {
                      echo "<option value=".$i.">".$region[$i]."</option>";
              }

            ?>
         </select>
      </div>
      <div id="province"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Script for updating:

```
 <?php
 $vector=array(1 =>array("CH","AQ","PE","TE"),
               2 => array("MT","PZ"),
               3 => array("CZ","CS","KR","RC","VV"));
 $id = $_GET['id'];
 if($id==0)
 {
     echo "";
 }
else{

   for($i=1;$i<(count($vector)+1);$i++)
   {
       $n=key($vector)
       if($n==$i)
       {
           echo "<select>";
           $content=current($vector);
           for($k=0;$k<count($content);$k++)
           {
             echo "<option>".$content[$k]."<option>";  
           }
           echo "</select>";
           break;
       }
       else
       {
           next($vector);
       }
   }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the id selector `#` in :

```
$('#province').load('select.php?id='+ value);
```

Hope this helps.

```js
function change(_this) {
  console.log(_this.value)
  $('#province').load('select.php?id='+ _this.value);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <select  onchange="change(this)">
    <option value="0"></option>
    <option value="1">Abruzzo</option>
    <option value="2">Basilicata</option>
    <option value="3">Calabria</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div id="province"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `#` from the `id` selector and the `;` from `$n=key($vector)` in your PHP file used for update. Also, if you tagged your question `jQuery` you should use it. Inline `onchange` is deprecated and I will recommend you **NOT** to use it anymore.

Change this:

```
$n=key($vector)
```

to this:

```
$n=key($vector);
```

**jQuery** code should look like this:

```
$('select').on('change', function() {
  var selected = $(this).find(":selected").val();
  $('#province').load('send.php?id=' + selected);
});
```

And **HTML** like this:

```
<div>
  <select name='select'>
    <?php for($i=0;$i<count($region);$i++) { echo "<option value=".$i. ">".$region[$i]. "</option>"; } ?>
  </select>
</div>
<div id="province"></div>
```

Comment: Hello, I first tried correcting the dumb mistakes I made, but that didn't fix the problem. Afterwards I tried the new solution but still nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

```
**Main page:**
<?php
$region= array("","Abruzzo", "Basilicata", "Calabria");
?>
<html>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#region").change(function(){
            var value=$(this).val();
            $("#province").load('select.php?id='+value);
        });
    });
   </script>

   <body>
      <div>
         <select  id="region" >
            <?php
              for($i=0;$i<count($region);$i++)
              {
                      echo "<option value=".$i.">".$region[$i]."</option>";
              }

            ?>
         </select>
      </div>
      <div id="province"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

```
**Script for updating:**

 <?php
 $vector=array(1 =>array("CH","AQ","PE","TE"),
               2 => array("MT","PZ"),
               3 => array("CZ","CS","KR","RC","VV"));
 $id = $_GET['id'];
 if($id==0)
 {
     echo "";
 }
else{

    if(array_key_exists($id,$vector))
    {
        echo "<select>";
        for($i=0;$i<(count($vector[$id]));$i++)
        {
            echo "<option>".$vector[$id][$i]."</option>";  
        }
       echo "</select>";
    }
}
?>
```